# Does aseh lecha rav mean you can only ask Halachic sheilohs to one rabbi?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot

I remember learning that it is also related to asking sheilos only to local rabbonim. Anyone has answer/sources? Thank you

Comment: Does kenei lecha chaver mean you should only have one friend?

Comment: כל הלומד תורה מרב אחד אינו רואה סימן ברכה לעולם.... הני מילי סברא אבל גמרא מרב אחד עדיף

Answer (score 2):

The understanding behind this teaching from Pirkei Avos 1:6 is more to demonstrate the need for fixing for yourself a mentor and guide, so that you can learn and grow from. Unlike a friend which you should 'acquire', here the advice is to take pains to formally 'make' for yourself a Rav as this is a necessary requirement for self growth.

[Rabbeinu Yonah](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.1.6?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&p2=Rabbeinu_Yonah_on_Pirkei_Avot.1.6.2&lang2=bi) writes:

> Yehoshua ben Perachia says, "Make for yourself a mentor, acquire for yourself a friend": As even if you know [as much] as him, make him a mentor upon you, since a person remembers better what he learned from his mentor than what a person learned on his own. And also because sometimes he will understand a thing better and it will come out that he will teach him - even as they are both equal in wisdom.

[Rambam](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.1.6?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&p2=Rambam_on_Pirkei_Avot.1.6&lang2=bi) notes:

> "Make for yourself a mentor": He means to say even if he is not fit to be your mentor; still place him upon you as a mentor, so that you can give and take (discuss and argue) with him, and as a result of this the study of wisdom will come to your hand. As the study of a man on his own is good, but his study from someone else will be better established in his hand and it will be more clear - and even if he is like him in wisdom or below him. And so did they elucidate the explanation of this commandment.

[Rabbeinu Ovadiah miBartenura](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.1.6?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&p2=Bartenura_on_Pirkei_Avot.1.6.1&lang2=bi) does note however that one should have a fixed Rav and not flit between Rabbinic figures which would perhaps point to the need to have one Rav for asking sheilos to:

> "Make for yourself a (Torah) mentor": Rambam explained, “Even though he is not fit to be your teacher, make him into your teacher and do not learn on your own.” And I heard, “'Make for yourself a teacher,' [meaning] that **he should take on one teacher from which always to learn – and not learn from one today and from another one tomorrow."** And even though they stated in tractate Avodah Zara 19, “One who learns from [only] one teacher will not see a sign of blessing;” they have already explained and said, “this applies to reasoning” - as it is good for him to hear the reasoning of the many - “but with concern to [memorization of traditional teachings], it is better from one teacher, so that [the student's] elocution not be damaged."

Comment: Thank you. So put simply we should turn to one person for halachic sheilos?

Comment: Yes definitely. In fact it is brought down in the sifrei halacha that you can't ask a Rov for one thing and then go to another Rov for another question if you know that they will rule more leniently